# C# WPF - Only allow certain file extensions

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, file, openfiledialog

I have an `OpenFileDialog` and I only want to allow `.txt` as a valid file for the users.

I know I can add a `Filter` to the `OpenFileDialog` like so:

```
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.DefaultExt = ".txt";
dialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
// Do something with the result
```

The problem however, is that I can still directly say something like `"test.jpg"` in the `OpenFileDialog` and then it opens this uploads this .jpg file. (Obviously it goes wrong somewhere later, but that doesn't matter for now.) I just want to know how I can restrict the user to only add ".txt" files, nothing else? (By directly validation it inside the `OpenFileDialog`, instead of doing it somewhere later.)

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to _prevent_ the user from changing the extension by typing it in, but you can inspect the extension immediately after they pick a file and report an error if it's illegal.

Comment: I think your options are to either check the extension after the user picks the file, or write your own file dialog.

Comment: Do you want the user to select everything except the .txt ???

Comment: Make clearer the question, so I can help you better

Comment: the `Filter` feature is used just to limit the files list so that user ***can easily choose a file*** of the right type. You cannot prevent him from faking the file extension and opening it ***unless*** you have some library helping you detect almost every common file structures (by reading the content instead of just basing on the extension).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant do that only in OpenFileDialog and even if you could its a bad limitation.

Using the `*.txt` example there are multiple files extensions that are plain text inside, `*.bat` or all the codding file extensions `*.cs`, `*.js`, etc...

You should not limit the user on what file he can put on it.

For more complex file types if your program cant handle the file passed by the user you should show an error not prevent the user from passing the file.

Comment: Ah ok, then I will just stick with the Filter. Right now it doesn't do anything with the content if it is of the incorrect format, I was just wondering if things like .bat or .exe could be harmful if injected, and wanted to prevent these kind of files by limiting what the user can put in.